# Doubt about derivative in an exercise

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I a working on an exercise about electromagnetic induction and got this:
$$ \Phi(B) = B_{0}\frac{t^2}{T^2} x(t) l $$$$\Longrightarrow f_{i} = -\frac{\Phi(B)}{dt} $$$$= -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (2tx(t)+t^2v(t))$$

My doubt is, is it correct to write $x(t)$ as $v(t)t$? This way I would do like this:
$$ \Phi(B) = B_{0}\frac{t^2}{T^2} [v(t)t] l $$$$\Longrightarrow f_{i} = -\frac{\Phi(B)}{dt}$$$$ = -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (2t^2v(t)+t^2v(t))$$$$ = -\frac{B_{0}}{T^2} (3t^2v(t))$$

Is this conceptually wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Don't change what you read, it was correct. The derivative of $t^2x(t)$ is $2tx(t)+t^2v(t)$, where *$v$ stands for the derivative of $x$*.

Comment: So the second way is not correct? If it was it would simplify so much my calculations

Comment: No it was not. Please read my answer more carefully.

Comment: Btw there is an $l$ at the end of some of your equalities but not all. Probably a misprint. I tried to suppress it but my edit was rejected.